# jQuery Ajax Firing success before beforesend on cordova iOS app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

The following excerpt changes the html of the login button until the response is received from the server.

When testing on my iPhone in an app build with Cordova. The alert is fired before the html of the login button has been updated. In a desktop browser it works as expected.

I've tried setting the cache and async to false but it makes no difference.

I can't think what else to try other than different ajax libraries?

Is there a better library to use for AJAX with cordova?

```
$.ajax({
    data: $data,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#btn-login').html('Logging In...');
    },
    success: function(r, status) {
         if (r.status == 'success') {
             getUser();
             initNavSwipeGestures();
             $('#page-index').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            alert(r.message);
        }
    },
    error: function(data, status) {
        alert(status);
    }
});
```

Comment: Which alert is being fired, success or error?

Comment: success Is being fired.

Comment: what is shown in alert then?

Comment: The response message from the server - incorrect login details

Comment: I don't understand, so the problem is neither ajax nor cordova? If you have incorrect login? I am lost.

Comment: If I enter incorrect login details, the alert is displayed, then the login button text is updated. The login button text should be updated as soon as the form is submitted. Success will also set the button text back to Login, meaning that the button text "logging in..." Will never be seen.

Comment: The "logging in..." will be performed asynchronously. It is quite possible that the success is being called instantaneously and hence the "logging in.." update is not visible to the naked eye. You can use a setTimeout(about 5 seconds) call to the success callback and check whether the status "logging in.." is being displayed before being updated.

Comment: The setTimout fixed it.

Comment: Do not use the setTimeout for production purpose :). It was just to test that the code is working as expected.

Comment: How about `async: true,` ?

Comment: Why not use setTimeOut?

Answer (score 1):

Success is called when it is successful - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/:

> success
>   Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>   A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Use "success" if you want to check what data is returned... otherwise you should use "complete".

Something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    data: $data,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#btn-login').html('Logging In...');
    },
    success: callback()
    },
    complete : function() {
         getUser();
         initNavSwipeGestures();
         $('#page-index').removeClass('active');        
    },
    error: function(data, status) {
        alert(status);
    }
});

var callback = function(response) {
   ///stuff to do after success here
};
```

Comment: Yep, success|error is also returned in my json response which represents whether the login was successful or not. which I check for within the success callback.

Comment: Have you tried testing it in safari? That is a much better testbed for iOS hybrid apps I find.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've not yet found a way to debug my app. I've only been using Cordova a couple of days.

Comment: It is invaluable... Inspect element - console for console.log("") - and the resources tab at the top of inspect element window will allow you to see local storage or webSQL databases. You also get much closer UI wise to the end result you will see on the phone. Really invaluable!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
$('#form-login').on('submit', function(e) {     
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($.trim($('#email').val()) === '' || $.trim($('#password').val()) === '') {
        return;
    }

    var loginBtn = Ladda.create( document.querySelector('#btn-login') );
    $data = $('#form-login').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        data: $data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#btn-login').addClass('isloading');
            loginBtn.start();
        },
        success: function(r, status) {
            setTimeout(loginResponse(r, loginBtn), 500);
        },
        error: function(data, status) {
            if (PLATFORM == 'desktop') {
                alert(status);
            } else {
                loginBtn.stop();
                $('#btn-login').removeClass('isloading');
                navigator.notification.alert(status, false, false);
            }
        }
    });
});

function loginResponse(r, loginBtn) {
    if ($('#btn-login').hasClass('isloading')) {
        if (r.status == 'success') {
            getUser();
            $('#page-index').removeClass('active');
        } else {
           if (PLATFORM == 'desktop') {
                alert(r.message);
            } else {
                navigator.notification.alert(r.message, false, false);
            }
        }
        loginBtn.stop();
        $('#btn-login').removeClass('isloading');
    } else {
        setTimeout(loginResponse(r, loginBtn), 500);
    }
}
```